# multidimensional knapsack coding in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am new here so bear with me in my best attempts at formulating detailed questions in keeping with the spirit of this site.

I am working within objective-c on an algorithm for a multidimensional knapsack problem in which there is a number on user determined constraints.  In this instance of baseball players:

I want to solve for creating a list from a database of players based on the cumulative constraints of:

- salary (equal or as close to 100 million)
- home runs (total equal to or as close to 150)
- RBIs (equal to or as close to 200)

and Yes or No selections of

- over/under age of 30: Yes or No
- Born outside U.S: Yes or No

I have had luck in finding some help with coding for a simple knapsack problem in which there are 2 dimensions involved (weight and value) but not so much in finding answers for multiple dimensions beyond that.

Can anyone offer some advice on this for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The name of this modified problem is called the Multi-objective knapsack problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of constraints, then probably the best way to formulate and solve this problem is as an integer linear program (you can look it up online). First divide each dimension by the target total sum so that each target total sum is 1.0. Then define a variable Xi for each player which is either 0 or 1 (i.e. greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1) which is 1 if the player i is included and 0 if the player i is not included. Then for each dimension (salary, homeruns, RBIs, etc.) let Ci be the normalized value for player i. Then you have the constraint C1X1 + C2X2 + ... + CnXn <= 1.0 for each dimension. And to get as close as possible to the target values overall, you want to maximize the grand total sum of all terms CiXi over all players and over all dimensions. There are integer linear programming solvers available online, some for free.